# My Nikon D5100 DSLR wont autofocus by itself

Tags: autofocus, nikon-d5100, continuous-autofocus

I bought the camera new recently the Nikon D5100 I put the lens on set it for automatic same with the camera I set it to AF-F but  in live view it wont focus unless I press the button to take pictures half way Is there a way to fix it and make it focus by not even touching it I use it to vlog and I spent a lot of money. The lens is 18-55mm vr lens

Answer (score 2):

No.  You are asking for it to keep trying auto focus all the time it is turned on... All the time you're carrying it around your neck without even aiming it. That would be hard on the battery. :)  It will auto focus when the shutter needs it.

Or, if you decided to activate the shutter so that it was recording movies continually, then it would auto focus continually.